# search input as per the selected item where select box has = or < and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using a dataTable and it has search box which is working for column " Age " to search data from table and its working fine but i have added a "Drop Down" above to input search box, now what i want is when i select " = " search box should show records if typed value matches in the column " Age " and if i select " < " search box should show records if column " Age " has items less than the value typed in the search box and same as when select " > " or " Cantains ".

SEARCH BOX SHOULD WORK BASED ON THE SELECTED ITEM.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>                


// <!-- data table default jason -->

function filterGlobal() {
  $('#example').DataTable().search(
    $('#global_filter').val(),
    $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
    $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
  ).draw();
}

function filterColumn(i) {
  $('#example').DataTable().column(i).search(
    $('#col' + i + '_filter').val(),
    $('#col' + i + '_regex').prop('checked'),
    $('#col' + i + '_smart').prop('checked')
  ).draw();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  //store the datatable object
  globDataTable = $('#example').DataTable();

  $('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
    filterGlobal();
  });

  $('input.column_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
    filterColumn($(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column'));
  });
});

// <!-- data table default jason end -->
```

```html
    <!-- search less than or greater than inputs -->
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Select to search:
                    <select id="selectAge">
                        <option value="1"> = </option>
                        <option value="1"> < </option>
                        <option value="1"> > </option>
                        <option value="1"> Contains </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="filter_col4" data-column="3">
                <td align="center" class="formcss" id="6">
                    input based on select :
                    <input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col3_filter">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- search less than or greater than inputs -->

    <!-- table  -->
    <table id="example" class="display dataTableShow" border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: See if this [range filtering example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) helps you set this up for your requirements.

Comment: No i wanna change the search box as per the select box as i have shown above..  please read my question once again.

Comment: I provided that link to show you the type of code you will need to perform the types of searches you want like all values greater than what is in the search box.  The code you have for filterGlobal and filterColumns won't do that.